# css absolute in fixed - overflow

Tags: css, css-position

I'm trying to add absolute item inside a fixed panel. My html is like :

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">test</a>
<div class="popup">Popup</div>
</li>
</ul>
```

The css :

```
ul
{
position:fixed;
left:10px;
top:0;
min-height:100%;
width:80px;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:#ccc;
color:#fff;
z-index:0;
}
ul li
{
position:relative;
}

.popup
{
width:400px;
border:1px solid #000;
display:none;
position:absolute;
color:#000;
z-index:1001;
}
```

My problem is the overflow behavior. If I disable overflow my popup work well but even in absolute position the popup is hidden. I need the overflow behavior to manage the scrolling effect if I have many content inside my ul tag.
I already tried to add relative position to the li, add a static height,width,min-width,min-height... as I so it in other post but it didn't solve my problem.
Here is the code : http://jsfiddle.net/jbval/SCzuu/

If someone have an idea.

Thanks for your help.

JB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dirty fix would be making the position of the popup class absolute, then set the width and height properties, and overflow.

```
 position:absolute;
 width:400px;
 height:400px;
 overflow:auto;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zcKbd/

Or, as stated in the previous answer, adding `position: fixed;` to the popup class.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
The first solution didn't work for me as I need the fixed instead of static for the ul item. The 2nd seems better, define the popup as fixed, I will try this.

Answer (score 0):

- How about making the `popup` also as fixed, see below.

  `.popup{
      position:fixed;
   }`

**Here's the fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/jm3Qh/

Comment: Thanks, as Mido says it could be a solution, i will try if there is any side effect.

Comment: Glad it helped.Then you might consider upvoting the answer as it may be beneficial for others.

Comment: I liked to upvoting but it seems I have not enough reputation yet to vote up.